# Bash - stderr captured before stdout

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to capture both stderr and stdout to a variable using the following code:

```
FileIDs="$(plutil -key "ID" file1.plist file2.plist file3.plist file4.plist 2>&1)"
```

However, when I echo the contents stored in the variable, any stderr lines show up first followed by stdout lines.

```
Error: File not found at path file3.plist
File1ID
File2ID
File4ID
```

If this `plutil -key "ID" file1.plist file2.plist file3.plist file4.plist 2>&1` is executed at a terminal the output is printed as expected:

```
File1ID
File2ID
Error: File not found at path file3.plist
File4ID
```

What can I do to capture both stderr and stdout in the correct order?

Comment: What platform, what versions of `plutil` and `bash`?

Comment: @mklement0 iOS, `plutil` written by Erica Sadun in the Erica Utilities package.

Answer (score 5):

You should not rely on ordering of stdout and stderr. They are two separate streams, and should be treated as such.

That said, the difference you're seeing is likely an effect of stdlib's buffering when output is not a tty. If you're on a GNU system, you can try

```
cmd=$(stdbuf -o 0 -e 0 plutil -key "ID" file1.plist file2.plist file3.plist file4.plist 2>&1)
```

on other systems, try the `unbuffer` command, installed as part of `expect`.

These will prevent buffering, and hopefully interleave the streams in the order you hope for.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those commands are available on my system, but thank you for explaining why that issue occurs.